# iOS : Thread safety

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

In my application I want to start same operation in multiple threads. I know writing same object in multiple threads is not safe. Anyone please help me to handle this situation.

Thanks
AKS

Comment: Refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853529/locking-an-object-from-being-accessed-by-multiple-threads-objective-c

Comment: refer this link [multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879034/how-to-wait-for-a-thread-to-finish-in-objective-c)
make group of thread and execute in queue