# How to know when multiple threads are done?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Looking at the [Earthquake CoreData example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ThreadedCoreData/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010723-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) from Apple, is it possible to know when the last XML file is parsed?
I have a similar project and I'd like to use the pull-to-refresh control, so the user can initiate a refresh. I can update the message in the refresh control to show progress as each file is parsed. The trick is how to call the endRefreshing to stop the refresh control after the last file is parsed.

Is this possible?

To complicate this, I'll be calling NSURLRequest for multiple sites

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What research have you done? You are far from the first to ask this type of question. There are several possible solutions. Update your question with what you have looked into so far.

Comment: I've seen other <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879034/how-to-wait-for-a-thread-to-finish-in-objective-c">examples</a> grouping the threads. Not sure if that would work in this case.

Comment: The duplicate I linked is just one of many similar questions.